# `compgen -A file -G './tmp/*.sh` unexpectedly shows ALL the files in directory ./ as well as the desired ones

Tags: bash, compgen

I expected that

```
compgen -A file -G './tmp/*.sh'
```

would show only files under `tmp/`, but it also showed all files in the current directory.

I have tried

```
compgen -A file -X  '!(tmp/*.sh)'
```

and

```
compgen -A file -X  "!(tmp/*.sh)"
```

but both result in null output.  Checking settings:

```
$ shopt|grep extglob
extglob         on
```

It's also worth noting that

```
compgen -A file tmp/*.sh
```

returns only the first valid candidate.  Incidentally, this exactly matches the default line completion result, e.g.

```
cp tmp/*.sh[TAB]
```

and

```
ls tmp/*.sh[TAB]
```

both expand out to only the first candidate.

Two questions:

1. Why?
2. Any way to get the expected result using only `compgen`?

The 'expected result' is for all the matching candidates to be returned, as would happen with `ls tmp/*.sh`

Comment: Your first command `-A files` is not valid as `files` is not a valid action name

Comment: Ditto. And if it was `file` then I *guess* `compgen -A file -G './tmp/*.sh'` is like `compgen -A file; compgen -G './tmp/*.sh'`.

Comment: What is your expected result?

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski - That's the answer - my mistake was assuming that '-A file' was required when dealing with filenames.  Using only '-G 'tmp/*.sh' will give the desired result.

Comment: No time for high quality answer now. I won't mind if you answer.

Answer (score 0):

@KamilMaciorowski's comment gave the answer.

My mistake was assuming that '-A file' was required when dealing with filenames. Using only `-G 'tmp/*.sh` will give the desired result.

The mistaken assumption resulted from there being many `-A` options, e.g. `file`, `host`, etc.  However, when `-G` is used, the domain being filenames is implicit because globs only work with filenames.